# PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN getting black where should be transparent

Tags: android, canvas, view, transparency

Where the image is transparent, I get black...

I've done the same thing for masking an image with another image on a Bitmap canvas and it worked perfectly, but when I try to mask inside a onDraw of a custom view, it doesn't work.

I tried everything, drawing rects before the image mask, paths, other images, everything and it stays black where it should be transparent. I search for a lot of other problems people had with the CLEAR mode but it didn't work.

Please Help!

```
    mBGPaint = new Paint();
    mBGPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mBGPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    mRectSrc = new Rect();
    mRectDst = new Rect();

    mask = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.big_balloon_path);
    maskPaint = new Paint();
    maskPaint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    maskPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));

    mRectSrc.set(0, 0, mask.getWidth(),mask.getHeight() );
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    mRectDst.set(0,0,this.getMeasuredWidth(),this.getMeasuredHeight());
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, this.getMeasuredWidth(), this.getMeasuredHeight(), mBGPaint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mask, mRectSrc, mRectDst, maskPaint);
```

Answer (score 5):

You may need to turn on software rendering in the initialization of the view:

```
setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

A lot of Android drawing commands silently fail or produce incorrect results when using hardware rendering, which is the default setting.

Comment: Which sucks, considering that it can be significantly slower, especially when dealing with animation.

Comment: @ollien Agreed, and on the other side of the coin, it seems insane to have APIs just fail and do nothing at the default settings.